# Merging two similar structs of different types

Tags: go, mgo

I have the following structs...

```
type Menu struct {
    Id          string     `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name        string     `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=name" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Description string     `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=description" json:"description,omitempty"`
    Mixers      []*Mixer   `protobuf:"bytes,4,rep,name=mixers" json:"mixers,omitempty"`
    Sections    []*Section `protobuf:"bytes,5,rep,name=sections" json:"sections,omitempty"`
}
```

And...

```
type Menu struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name        string        `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Description string        `json:"description" bson:"description"`
    Mixers      []Mixer       `json:"mixers" bson:"mixers"`
    Sections    []Section     `json:"sections" bson:"sections"`
}
```

I basically need to convert between the two struct types, I've attempted to use mergo, but that can only merge structs that are assignable to one another. The only solution I have so far is iterating through each struct, converting the ID by re-assigning it and converting its type between string and bson.ObjectId. Then iterating through each map field and doing the same. Which feels like an inefficient solution.

So I'm attempting to use reflection to be more generic in converting between the two ID's. But I can't figure out how I can effectively merge all of the other fields that do match automatically, so I can just worry about converting between the ID types.

Here's the code I have so far...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Sub struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId
}

type PbSub struct {
    Id string
}

type PbMenu struct {
    Id   string
    Subs []PbSub
}

type Menu struct {
    Id   bson.ObjectId
    Subs []Sub
}

func main() {
    pbMenus := []*PbMenu{
        &PbMenu{"1", []PbSub{PbSub{"1"}}},
        &PbMenu{"2", []PbSub{PbSub{"1"}}},
        &PbMenu{"3", []PbSub{PbSub{"1"}}},
    }

    newMenus := Serialise(pbMenus)
    fmt.Println(newMenus)
}

type union struct {
    PbMenu
    Menu
}

func Serialise(menus []*PbMenu) []Menu {
    newMenus := []Menu{}
    for _, v := range menus {
        m := reflect.TypeOf(*v)
        fmt.Println(m)
        length := m.NumField()
        for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
            field := reflect.TypeOf(v).Field(i)
            fmt.Println(field.Type.Kind())
            if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Map {
                fmt.Println("is map")
            }
            if field.Name == "Id" && field.Type.String() == "string" {

                // Convert ID type
                id := bson.ObjectId(v.Id)
                var dst Menu
                dst.Id = id

                // Need to merge other matching struct fields

                newMenus = append(newMenus, dst)
            }
        }
    }
    return newMenus
}
```

I'm can't just manually re-assign the fields because I'm hoping to detect maps on the structs fields and recursively perform this function on them, but the fields won't be the same on embedded structs.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: [`bson.ObjectId`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#ObjectId) is defined as `type ObjectId string` so you can use type casting (to `string`) instead of reflection. For clarification, are both structs has *same fields with different type* as shown in question, or it may has different fields? If the former is true, I think you can *marshal* the first struct to JSON then *unmarshal* the JSON to second struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is probably better to write your own converter, because you will always have some cases that are not covered by existing libs\tools for that.

My initial implementation of it would be something like this: [basic impl of structs merger](https://play.golang.org/p/UBCq0waIEe)

Comment: This looks very smart, I've been trying it our against my current problem though, and am I right in thinking this only applies to root fields? So for example, when this code reaches a field which is a map, it's not converting that underlying map, and the Id fields within that map. So I need to be able to run this recursively across any field that's a map I guess?

Comment: For fields that have different types you must provide your own `Translator`. If you want to convert field of type `map[MyID]MyStruct` into `map[int]OtherStruct` you should defined `Bind` for those fields with `Translator` to convert them. Take a look on extended example with map field here: https://play.golang.org/p/crYjG2qGFq